# PGFplots: dashed lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, node-connections, dateplot

How can I do to draw vertical dashed lines which connect markers of one serie with the respective one of the other serie?
X axes for both plot is the same.

## MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage[]{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{title style={at={(0.5,1.07)}}}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,1.01)},anchor=south}}
    \begin{axis} [  scale only axis,
                    ymin = 0, ymax = 8.1,
                    axis y line*=left,
                    grid=major,
                    xlabel={Data e ora},
                    ylabel={Velocità down-load (Mib)},
                    title={\textbf{Rilievo velocità internet}},
                    width=10cm, height=7cm,
                    date coordinates in=x,
                    xticklabel style=
                    {rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},
                    xticklabel=\day-\month-\year,
                    date ZERO=2014-02-03]
                 ]
        \addplot+
        [thick,cyan,smooth]
        coordinates {
        (2014-02-03 09:15,  7.93)
        (2014-02-03 14:24,  3.11)
        (2014-02-03 15:22,  6.22)
        (2014-02-03 21:05,  4.41)
        (2014-02-04 08:53,  6.26)
        (2014-02-04 17:13,  5.94)
        (2014-02-04 22:00,  1.15)
        (2014-02-05 09:12,  6.87)
        (2014-02-05 15:01,  6.72)
        (2014-02-06 09:28,  7.05)
        (2014-02-06 21:34,  1.2)
        (2014-02-06 23:14,  2.96)
        (2014-02-07 18:01,  6.84)
        (2014-02-08 10:18,  6.77)
        (2014-02-09 14:38,  6.65)
        (2014-02-09 21:14,  1.79)
        (2014-02-10 09:35,  6.33)
        (2014-02-10 21:26,  2.35)
        (2014-02-11 19:56,  3.70)
        (2014-02-12 17:17,  6.51)
        (2014-02-13 15:32,  5.55)
        (2014-02-14 09:13,  6.30)
        (2014-02-14 21:33,  6.24)};
        \label{Dplot}
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis} [  scale only axis,
                    ymax = 0.43,
                    axis y line*=right,
                    ylabel={Velocità up-load (Mib)},
                    width=10cm, height=7cm,
                    legend style={draw=none},
                    legend cell align=left,
                    legend columns={2},
                    date coordinates in=x,
                    xticklabel style=
                    {rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},
                    xticklabel=\day-\month-\year,
                    date ZERO=2014-02-03,
                    axis x line=none
                 ]
        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Dplot}\addlegendentry{Down-load}
        \addplot+
        [thick,orange,smooth,mark=*,mark options={fill=red}]
        coordinates {
        (2014-02-03 09:15,  0.35)
        (2014-02-03 14:24,  0.36)
        (2014-02-03 15:22,  0.36)
        (2014-02-03 21:05,  0.36)
        (2014-02-04 08:53,  0.37)
        (2014-02-04 17:13,  0.34)
        (2014-02-04 22:00,  0.34)
        (2014-02-05 09:12,  0.33)
        (2014-02-05 15:01,  0.36)
        (2014-02-06 09:28,  0.37)
        (2014-02-06 21:34,  0.36)
        (2014-02-06 23:14,  0.37)
        (2014-02-07 18:01,  0.36)
        (2014-02-08 10:18,  0.36)
        (2014-02-09 14:38,  0.37)
        (2014-02-09 21:14,  0.34)
        (2014-02-10 09:35,  0.37)
        (2014-02-10 21:26,  0.35)
        (2014-02-11 19:56,  0.35)
        (2014-02-12 17:17,  0.36)
        (2014-02-13 15:32,  0.37)
        (2014-02-14 09:13,  0.36)
        (2014-02-14 21:33,  0.37)};
        \addlegendentry{Up-load}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just add `dashed` to the addplot command. `[dashed, thick,cyan,smooth]` You can find more linestyles in the `pgfplots` manual

Comment: In this way I connect markers of the same series but I want to connect markers of one series with the respective markers of the other series

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `error bar` functionality for this. Since the plots are on different axes, you'll need to make sure that you know the scaling factor by explicitly setting `ymin` and `ymax`.

I've rescaled your upload axis to include 0. I feel that this axis range represents the data more accurately. In your original scale, it looked like the upload rate was almost as volatile as the download rate, but that's really not the case. The casual reader will not notice that the upload axis only covered a very narrow range.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage[]{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
        2014-02-03 09:15,7.93,0.35
        2014-02-03 14:24,3.11,0.36
        2014-02-03 15:22,6.22,0.36
        2014-02-03 21:05,4.41,0.36
        2014-02-04 08:53,6.26,0.37
        2014-02-04 17:13,5.94,0.34
        2014-02-04 22:00,1.15,0.34
        2014-02-05 09:12,6.87,0.33
        2014-02-05 15:01,6.72,0.36
        2014-02-06 09:28,7.05,0.37
        2014-02-06 21:34,1.2,0.36
        2014-02-06 23:14,2.96,0.37
        2014-02-07 18:01,6.84,0.36
        2014-02-08 10:18,6.77,0.36
        2014-02-09 14:38,6.65,0.37
        2014-02-09 21:14,1.79,0.34
        2014-02-10 09:35,6.33,0.37
        2014-02-10 21:26,2.35,0.35
        2014-02-11 19:56,3.7,0.35
        2014-02-12 17:17,6.51,0.36
        2014-02-13 15:32,5.55,0.37
        2014-02-14 09:13,6.3,0.36
        2014-02-14 21:33,6.24,0.37
}\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{title style={at={(0.5,1.07)}}}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,1.01)},anchor=south}}
    \begin{axis} [  scale only axis,
                    ymin = 0, ymax = 8,
                    axis y line*=left,
                    grid=major,
                    xlabel={Data e ora},
                    ylabel={Velocità down-load (Mib)},
                    title={\textbf{Rilievo velocità internet}},
                    width=10cm, height=7cm,
                    date coordinates in=x,
                    xticklabel style=
                    {rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},
                    xticklabel=\day-\month-\year,
                    date ZERO=2014-02-03]
                 ]
        \addplot+
        [thick,cyan]
        table {\datatable};
        \label{Dplot}
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis} [  scale only axis,
                        ymin=0,
                    ymax = 0.8,
                    axis y line*=right,
                    ylabel={Velocità up-load (Mib)},
                    width=10cm, height=7cm,
                    legend style={draw=none},
                    legend cell align=left,
                    legend columns={2},
                    date coordinates in=x,
                    xticklabel style=
                    {rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},
                    xticklabel=\day-\month-\year,
                    date ZERO=2014-02-03,
                    axis x line=none
                 ]
        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Dplot}\addlegendentry{Down-load}
        \addplot+
        [thick,orange,mark=*,mark options={fill=red},
        error bars/y explicit,
        error bars/y dir=minus,
        error bars/error mark={},
        error bars/error bar style={gray, dashed}]
        table [y index=2, y error expr=(\thisrowno{2}-\thisrowno{1}/10)] {\datatable};
        \addlegendentry{Up-load}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you really want one axis to start from a non-zero value, you have to subtract that offset from the length of the error bars. So if your first axis has a range of 8 and your second axis has a range of 0.1 with an offset of 0.3, the expression for calculating the length of the error bars would be

```
 y error expr=\thisrowno{2}-\thisrowno{1}/(8/0.1)-0.3
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage[]{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
        2014-02-03 09:15,7.93,0.35
        2014-02-03 14:24,3.11,0.36
        2014-02-03 15:22,6.22,0.36
        2014-02-03 21:05,4.41,0.36
        2014-02-04 08:53,6.26,0.37
        2014-02-04 17:13,5.94,0.34
        2014-02-04 22:00,1.15,0.34
        2014-02-05 09:12,6.87,0.33
        2014-02-05 15:01,6.72,0.36
        2014-02-06 09:28,7.05,0.37
        2014-02-06 21:34,1.2,0.36
        2014-02-06 23:14,2.96,0.37
        2014-02-07 18:01,6.84,0.36
        2014-02-08 10:18,6.77,0.36
        2014-02-09 14:38,6.65,0.37
        2014-02-09 21:14,1.79,0.34
        2014-02-10 09:35,6.33,0.37
        2014-02-10 21:26,2.35,0.35
        2014-02-11 19:56,3.7,0.35
        2014-02-12 17:17,6.51,0.36
        2014-02-13 15:32,5.55,0.37
        2014-02-14 09:13,6.3,0.36
        2014-02-14 21:33,6.24,0.37
}\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{title style={at={(0.5,1.07)}}}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,1.01)},anchor=south}}
    \begin{axis} [  scale only axis,
                    ymin = 0, ymax = 8,
                    axis y line*=left,
                    grid=major,
                    xlabel={Data e ora},
                    ylabel={Velocità down-load (Mib)},
                    title={\textbf{Rilievo velocità internet}},
                    width=10cm, height=7cm,
                    date coordinates in=x,
                    xticklabel style=
                    {rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},
                    xticklabel=\day-\month-\year,
                    date ZERO=2014-02-03]
                 ]
        \addplot+
        [thick,cyan]
        table {\datatable};
        \label{Dplot}
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis} [  scale only axis,
                        ymin=0.3,
                    ymax = 0.4,
                    ytick = {0.3,0.35,0.4},
                    axis y line*=right,
                    ylabel={Velocità up-load (Mib)},
                    width=10cm, height=7cm,
                    legend style={draw=none},
                    legend cell align=left,
                    legend columns={2},
                    date coordinates in=x,
                    xticklabel style=
                    {rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},
                    xticklabel=\day-\month-\year,
                    date ZERO=2014-02-03,
                    axis x line=none, clip=false
                 ]
        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Dplot}\addlegendentry{Down-load}
        \addplot+
        [thick,orange,mark=*,mark options={fill=red},
        error bars/y explicit,
        error bars/y dir=minus,
        error bars/error mark={},
        error bars/error bar style={gray, dashed}]
        table [y index=2, y error expr=\thisrowno{2}-\thisrowno{1}/(8/0.1)-0.3] {\datatable};
        \addlegendentry{Up-load}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a very good starting point. Thanks for your help.
but I need to set ymin different than 0. How can I do?

Comment: @marchetto: I've edited my answer.

Comment: I really want one axis to start from a non-zero value. Thanks